# SQL Error: Must be GROUPed or used in aggregate function

Tags: oracle, group-by

I have just created a SQL statement in Crystal Reports using the command feature, but I am having issues with displaying the data. The error reads:

> Attribute FUND_ACCT_REG_VIEW.FUND._ACCT_NO must be GROUPed or used in an aggregate function.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT substr(work_item.wi_name, 1 + instr(work_item.wi_name, '['), 6) p2
    ,substr(work_item.wi_name, 1, 4) wi_name
    ,substr(pr_line_item.prac_no, 7, 16) prac_no
    ,moa_code
    ,resource_code
    ,nvl(certified_us_amt, 0) - nvl(deob_amt, 0) + nvl(obli_excess_commit_amt, 0) + nvl(pr_interest_amt, 0) COMMITTED
    ,nvl(certified_us_amt, 0) - nvl(deob_amt, 0) + nvl(obli_excess_commit_amt, 0) - nvl(unoblig_us_bal_amt, 0) + nvl(pr_interest_amt, 0) obligated
    ,unoblig_us_bal_amt unoblig
    ,max(receive_org_code) receive
    ,substr(org_name, 1, 13) org_name
    ,fund_acct_reg_view.fund_acct_no fund_acct
    ,decode(fund_acct_reg_view.fund_acct_no, 'J177777', 'SA', 'J177778', 'SA', 'J177779', 'SA', 'J177768', 'OTHER CWE', 'J176716', 'OTHER CWE', 'J176717', 'OTHER CWE', 'J177780', 'CONST', 'DESIGN') type
FROM pr_line_item
    ,work_item
    ,pr_amend
    ,wm_organization
    ,fund_acct_reg_view
WHERE ((substr(work_item.wi_name, 1 + instr(work_item.wi_name, '['), 6) = '%153719%'))
    AND work_item.wi_code = pr_line_item.wi_code
    AND pr_line_item.prac_no = pr_amend.prac_no
    AND fund_acct_reg_view.fund_acct_no NOT LIKE 'OA%'
    AND (
        ABS(nvl(certified_us_amt, 0) - nvl(deob_amt, 0) + nvl(obli_excess_commit_amt, 0)) > 0
        OR nvl(obli_excess_commit_amt, 0) > 0
        )
    AND fund_acct_reg_view.fund_acct_no NOT LIKE 'J169479'
    AND receive_org_code = org_code
    AND pr_line_item.fund_acct_no = fund_acct_reg_view.fund_acct_no
GROUP BY substr(work_item.wi_name, 1 + instr(work_item.wi_name, '['), 6)
    ,substr(pr_line_item.prac_no, 7, 16)
    ,nvl(certified_us_amt, 0) - nvl(deob_amt, 0) + nvl(obli_excess_commit_amt, 0) + nvl(pr_interest_amt, 0)
    ,nvl(certified_us_amt, 0) - nvl(deob_amt, 0) + nvl(obli_excess_commit_amt, 0) - nvl(unoblig_us_bal_amt, 0) + nvl(pr_interest_amt, 0)
    ,unoblig_us_bal_amt
    ,resource_code
    ,pr_line_item.fund_acct_no
    ,decode(fund_acct_reg_view.fund_acct_no, 'J177777', 'SA', 'J177778', 'SA', 'J177779', 'SA', 'J177768', 'OTHER CWE', 'J176716', 'OTHER CWE', 'J176717', 'OTHER CWE', 'J177780', 'CONST', 'DESIGN')
    ,substr(org_name, 1, 13)
    ,substr(work_item.wi_name, 1, 4)
    ,moa_code
ORDER BY type
    ,fund_acct
    ,moa_code
    ,resource_code
    ,receive
```

After testing the code multiple times, I keep having the issued with either this field or another field. I am hoping that the issue it at the tail end of my code and someone may know a simple quick fix. I have spent almost all day trying to read up on this error, but I can't see how other solution apply to my situation.

Answer (score 1):

You use `fund_acct_reg_view.fund_acct_no fund_acct`, in SELECT but use `pr_line_item.fund_acct_no` in GROUP BY. Use `fund_acct_no` from the same table in both cases.